# Use selenium webdriver to extract dynamic table displayed on the website

Tags: javascript, ajax, selenium

I am trying to parse a website where table content is loaded through javascript-ajax call..

```
function buildTable() {
        // render spinner over dataset summary table
        var overlay = document.getElementById("summary");
        enableOverlay(overlay, true, true, "30px");
        // request dataset summary from server
        $.ajax({
          url: "/ProteoSAFe/MassiveServlet",
          data: { "function":"", "mid":dataset_name },
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            complete: function(data) {
               var stats = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
               var filesize = document.getElementById("filesize");
               filesize.innerHTML = stats.filesize;
              }
```

In HTML :

```
                <table>
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Number of Files:</td>
                    <td id="filecount"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Total Size:</td>
                    <td id="filesize"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="spectra_row" style="display:hidden">
                    <td>Spectra:</td>
                    <td id="spectra"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Subscribers:</td>
                    <td id="subscribers"></td>
                </tr>
```

I am using below code in selenium:

```
 List<WebElement> tables = div.findElements(By.tagName("table"));
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(tables));
  for (WebElement table : tables) {
     List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
       for (WebElement row : allRows) {
         List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
                          for (WebElement cell : cells) { System.out.println("content >>   " + cell.getText());
                          }
                      }
         }
```

My question is : Its extracting only couple of table cells ..I want to extract content of all the table.
Is there any other way to extract the table content. Please advise.

Comment: can you explain the "couple of table cells" it is extracting?  Are they the only visible ones?  Or are the 1st ones?  Have you determined what the logic might be for only those few cells/

Comment: What does the HTML of the table look like *after* the table has been populated? What is *all* the code you're using - the code you've shared doesn't show how you get `row`.

Comment: @webdad3 I am able to display values of subscribers , filesize but not filecount.

Comment: @MarkLapierreI have updated the code..

Comment: I don't see any values in the table? make sure your ajax call is complete

Comment: @kushal.table values are updated from javascript ..